# Ubuntu 14.04 Crashed and I don't know how to get back

Tags: 14.04, grub2, recovery-mode

Ubuntu 14.04 crashed and I don't know how to get it back. I'm stuck on GNU GRUB version `2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2`. I've tried going to Advanced Options and choosing a recovery mode, but to no avail. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ubuntu Installation Cd then once you boot it go through option `try Ubuntu...` this will takes you to a live session.

Once you are in you can try to update your GRUB and restart. If this doesn't help boot again to liveCD and make a backup of your data then try to figure what crashes your system. If you can't get reasons you can just reinstall.

> **To install grub from live cd**

Boot from a Live CD.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

replace sdaX with your Ubuntu partition (mostly sda1)

Install the GRUB2 boot loader:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

Rermark that installing grub to harddisk  itself not the Ubuntu partition

Then Unmount the Ubuntu partition

```
sudo umount /dev/sdaX
```

Now restart and test it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I do not have a CD Drive. I have a USB stick that should have the most recent version of Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

Comment: Same solution still available for using pendrive

Comment: The command-line is GRUB is not allowing sudo commands.

Comment: Those commands run in the live session not in the Grub menu.

Comment: Oh, well I can't even get into a live session.

Comment: Error: invalid environment block.

Comment: Error: invalid arch-independent ELF magic.